# Load assemblies with injector module

Tags: c#, performance, .net, linq

How can I improve the performance of this method or is it already good?

```
private static void LoadAssembliesWithInjectorModule(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files)
{
    var moduleType = typeof (InjectorModule);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);

            var moduleTypes = from assemblyType in assembly.GetTypes()
                              where moduleType.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType) && !assemblyType.IsAbstract
                              select assemblyType;

            if (!moduleTypes.Any()) continue;

            foreach (var instance in moduleTypes.Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type) as InjectorModule))
            {
                instance.Load();
            }
        }
        catch (BadImageFormatException)
        {
            //Files that aren't class libraries will throw this exception, just eat it and move on.
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            throw new AppDomainUnloadedException(string.Format("Error loading {0} exception {1} loading errors {2}", file.FullName, e.Message, e.LoaderExceptions), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we know? Is it good enough for your intended usage? Is this method a bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @svick There is a theoretical chance that this could be very intensive depending on the amount of assemblies are available for it to pick up, so it all depends. If there's a small amount, it should never be an issue, but if there's a large amount then it possibly could be. I'm looking to see if there is possibly any way to improve upon what there is now.

Comment: Looks pretty much like every dynamic loader I've seen. My guess is that this method is only called once per program activation? If so, unless you're talking close to a thousand assemblies being loaded, it's not going to be a significant percentage of your program's execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest swapping the checks on this line from

`where moduleType.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType) && !assemblyType.IsAbstract`

to

`where !assemblyType.IsAbstract && moduleType.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType)`

Checking a boolean property will be faster than a method call to check the type. If it's not abstract why check the type?

You might also want to filter further by requiring that it is a class:

```
where assemblyType.IsClass 
      && !assemblyType.IsAbstract 
      && moduleType.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType)
```

Comment: I agree with your changes as it would make sense to check something that's already set rather than making a method call first.